# trying to make a simple program to test numbers in the Collatz Conjecture

Tags: java

I just want to preface this by saying that I am a coding noob. This is probably the most advanced code I have written.

I am trying to test numbers in the Collatz conjecture. My input variable is supposed to increase by 1 after the loop gets to 1. If it isn't 1, then it goes to the other 2 functions. If the number is even, it is divided by 2. If it is odd it is multiplied by 3 and has 1 added to it.

The reason this math equation is so interesting is that we do not know if all numbers get too one given enough times run through this equation.

I also know that there is no break; in the loop, but that is not the problem. My problem is the output. Here is my code:

```
public class class1 {

static int output = 0;
static int input = 1;
static int turn = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    output = input;
    for (;;) {
        if(input != 1){
            if (input % 2 == 0) {
                even(input);
                System.out.println("output = " + input + " turn = " + turn);
            } else if (input % 2 == 1) {
                odd(input);
                System.out.println("output = " + input + " turn = " + turn);
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("done in " + turn + " turns");
            turnsTested++;
            turn = 0;
            output = input;
        }
        turn++;
    }
}//end main


public static int even(int input2) {
    input = input / 2;
    return input;

}

public static int odd(int input2) {
    input = (input * 3);
    input++;
    return input;
     }
}//end class
```

The Output for a run of this code below:

```
output = 2734 turn = 105

output = 1367 turn = 106

output = 4102 turn = 107

output = 2051 turn = 108

output = 6154 turn = 109

output = 3077 turn = 110

output = 9232 turn = 111

output = 4616 turn = 112

output = 2308 turn = 113

output = 1154 turn = 114

output = 577 turn = 115

output = 1732 turn = 116

output = 866 turn = 117

output = 433 turn = 118

output = 1300 turn = 119

output = 650 turn = 120

output = 325 turn = 121

output = 976 turn = 122

output = 488 turn = 123

output = 244 turn = 124

output = 122 turn = 125

output = 61 turn = 126

output = 184 turn = 127

output = 92 turn = 128

output = 46 turn = 129

output = 23 turn = 130

output = 70 turn = 131

output = 35 turn = 132

output = 106 turn = 133

output = 53 turn = 134

output = 160 turn = 135

output = 80 turn = 136

output = 40 turn = 137

output = 20 turn = 138

output = 10 turn = 139

output = 5 turn = 140

output = 16 turn = 141

output = 8 turn = 142

output = 4 turn = 143

output = 2 turn = 144

output = 1 turn = 145

done in 146 turns
```

So I have an error. I can't find my problem.

Comment: So what's the error? Is it the off-by-one discrepancy at the end? (That is, is the output supposed to be "done in 145 turns" instead of 146? Or is the error something else?

Comment: Also, since `input` starts out as 1, how does it ever get changed? The only way to change `input` is to call `even()` or `odd()`, but those only get called on the `if (input != 1)` branch of the loop. Is this the actual code that's producing that output?

Comment: the problem is that it input starts as 1, when input is 1 add 1. Yet my first output is 2734

Comment: This can't possibly be the code that produces the output you report. For one thing, it doesn't compile (`turnsTested` isn't declared). For another, when I added a declaration for `turnsTested` and ran the code, I got an endless stream of identical output lines "done in 1 turns". You're not going to get any decent help until you show us your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (input % 2 == 0) {
            // transforming a primitive method argument in a function is
            // *NOT* reflected on the variable passed as argument:
            // a call to the function will pass *the value* of the variable 
            // and not the reference to the variable
            input = even(input);
            System.out.println("output = " + input + " turn = " + turn);
        } else if (input % 2 == 1) {
            // see above
            input = odd(input);
            System.out.println("output = " + input + " turn = " + turn);
        }
```